# Cheap way to frequently fly during the weekend to visit friends/family/girlfriend? European City Hopping

Tags: air-travel, budget, europe, hungary, weekends

On multiple and frequent occasions I want to fly for a visit during a weekend (EIN -> BUD), without it interfering much with my job. For this reason I'm only somewhat flexible when it comes to the day and time of flight, but completely flexible to which week I am flying.

What is the best approach to get the most flights so a fixed location, at a somewhat fixed time on random weekends?

---

My current experience is it's best to book around 2 1/2 Months in advance, learn to enjoy REALLY early Monday mornings and the convenient location usually is somewhat "cheap" as it avoids needing to pay extra for the extra commute or the extra time off work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the website Kayak.com and use the "3 days before/after" to search.  Note there is only one airline that flies between Eindhoven and Budapest.

See the image. You can click the days to find the lowest price combination for trips originating from Eindhoven.

Also try trips originating from Budapest to come the other direction... they may be priced differently.

Finally, plan on making a lot of these trips and see what frequent flyer privileges you can get with Wizz air... for further cost optimization.

[image]

Comment: I love the price trend, I wish I could get more information like this to see when to book ideally in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Wizz Air does not have a frequent flier programme but it does have a [Wizz Discount Club](http://wizzair.com/en-GB/travel_services/Wizz_Xclusive_Club) which seems to be just what you need: an annual €29.99 gives you 
a €10 discount on ticket fares with the following conditions:

> Discount is available on all fares from €19.99. Discounts are not available for and excluding flights operated by Wizz Air Ukraine. Fares include taxes, non optional charges, and one small cabin bag (42x32x25cm), but exclude administration fee.

Also, Skyscanner is *way* better than Kayak for this: it can show a whole month.